# React Native: Panresponder switch from TouchableHighlight to Panresponder while preserving touch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

I currently have a main component in react native which, based on app state, renders one of two view components. The first is a TouchableOpacity bubble, while the second contains an identical looking panresponder bubble at the exact location of this TouchableOpacity.

After long pressing the first TouchableOpacity, the first view fires a state update to the main parent component, which then(due to the updated state), renders the second view, a draggable panresponder at the position of the bubble which was held down.

**Problem**: After long pressing the bubble in the first view and rendering the second view, the PanResponder is unable to pick up the touch from the first view. The user is forced to release their finger from the screen, and press down again to begin dragging the panresponder. This needs to occur in one smooth action. How do I preserve the touch event, so that the second view is able to detect the already pressed down touch from the touchableopacity?

**Potential Thread Towards Solution** I know already that using two Touchable Opacities, the press is preserved! I've attached the code from this experiment below as well! After long pressing the first component, the second touchableopacity becomes opaque immediately, and remains this way until released(However it is unable to call its onLongPress function).

Thanks!

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Animated, PanResponder} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  var [status,updateStatus] = useState(true)
  return (
    <View>
      {status?
        <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:"red",height:50,width:50,left:150,top:150}} 
        onLongPress={()=>
          {updateStatus(false);
          }
        }
        />
        :
        <Bubble updateStatus={(status)=>{updateStatus(true)}}></Bubble>
      }
    </View>
  );
}

export function Bubble(props) {

  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY())
  const panResponder = React.useMemo(() => PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
          return true
      },
      onPanResponderGrant: async (evt, gestureState) => {
          pan.current.setOffset(pan.current.__getValue());
          pan.current.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
          return Animated.event([
              null, { dx: pan.current.x, dy: pan.current.y }
          ])(evt, gestureState)
      }
      ,
      onPanResponderRelease: async (e, gesture) => {
          pan.current.flattenOffset();
          Animated.spring(pan.current, {
              toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
              friction: 5,
          }).start(() => {
            props.updateStatus(false)
          }
          );
      }
  }), []);
  const panStyle = {
      transform: pan.current.getTranslateTransform()
  }
  return (
      <View>
          <Animated.View
              {...panResponder.panHandlers}
              style={[panStyle,
                  {
                      height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: "green", position: "absolute",
                      top: 150, left: 150
                  }]}>

          </Animated.View>
      </View>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function App() {
  var [status,updateStatus] = useState(true)
  return (
    <View>
      {status?
        <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:"red",height:50,width:50,left:150,top:150}} 
        onLongPress={()=>
          {updateStatus(false);
          }
        }
        />
        :
        <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:"green",height:50,width:50,left:150,top:150}}
        
        onLongPress={(status)=>{updateStatus(true)}}></TouchableOpacity>
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```